# Ember cli Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, ember.js, firebase, ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

I am an ember noob and i originally built my app without ember-cli it works fine
then i got the bright idea of rebuilding my very simple app with ember-cli what could possible go wrong:)

Everything works the same in both apps until ember throws an error and points me to line 52 in my verse controller keep in mind that this file is exactly the same in my non ember-cli version

Update i just put a lot of spaces where line 52 was and now it is saying the error is on line 53 which is empty:(((

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    sortProperties:["time"],
    sortAscending:true,
    start:new Date(),
    count:0,
    incorrect:0,
    startReview:true,
    showHighScores:false,

    actions:{

        startReview:function(){
            this.set('startReview',false);
            this.set("showHighScores",false);
            this.start = new Date();
            this.count = 0;
            this.incorrect = 0;
            console.log(this.count);
        },

        showHighScores:function(){
            this.toggleProperty("showHighScores");
        },

        checkCorrectness:function(word){
            var textArray = this.get("model.text").split(" ");
            var length = textArray.length;
            console.log(this.array);
            if(word === textArray[this.count]){

                console.log("correct");
                this.count++;
                console.log(this.count);
            }else{
                console.log("Incorrect");
                this.incorrect++;
            }
            if(length === this.count){
                var finish = new Date();
                var time = finish-this.start;
                var accuracy = (this.count/(this.count+this.incorrect)*100);
                alert("You took "+time/1000+" seconds! With "+accuracy+"% accuracy!");
                this.saveResult(time);
                this.set('startReview',true);
            }
        },
    },
    randomizer:function(){
        this.set("randomArray",this.get("model.text").split(" ").randomize());      
    **}.observes("startReview"),**//The offending line

    saveResult:function(timeTaken){
        var date = new Date(),
            userName = "TimTheGreat";


        var score = this.store.createRecord('score',{
            userName:userName,
            date:date,
            time:timeTaken,
            verse:this.get('model'),
        });

        var controller = this;
        var scores = controller.get("model.scores");
        score.save().then(function(score){
            scores.addObject(score).then(function(){
                controller.get("model").save();
            });

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing Ember is not loaded when this is run. You can try adding an observer without extending the function prototype. http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/observers/#toc_without-prototype-extensions

Comment: @lxe He's using ember-cli, he'd have to have screwed up a lot of stuff pretty badly to not have ember loaded ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offending line is actually the line before.

```
this.set("randomArray",this.get("model.text").split(" ").randomize());
```

Neither in Ember nor in native javascript do arrays have a `randomize` method.  This is something either you or another lib you were using added before.

Comment: Doh! how could i not have noticed that? I extended the array prototype and fogot to add the file now i have to figure out how to add that file...